# Magento Newsletter Signup Source

Tags: magento, enterprise, mailchimp

I'm currently integrating Mailchimp with Magento, using Ebizmarts MageMonkey module, for an e-commerce store. The data I need to send to Mailchimp is first & last name, email, and signup source/location e.g header, footer, checkout, etc...I have successfully been able to get first name, last name, and email, but cannot figure out how to get signup source/location.

I've done a lot of research for a way to get the signup source/location when a user opts in to our newsletter. I haven't be successful in finding anything other than how to move the newsletter block to a different location on the page.

So my question is, When a customer or guest signs up for our newsletter is there a way to get the location where they signed up, e.g header, footer, checkout, etc...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just modify a hidden input with a hard coded value per source/location?

Comment: @Jake I have considered that option, however, I see problems arising in the future with that route. We currently have 2 places on our homepage where a customer can sign up. One form is set from a template file and the other a static block. So right now yes I could hardcode the values. If another developer has to put the signup form in the middle of a cms page and they use the template file which has `value="footer"` then wrong data is being sent. So I'd like to figure out a way to grab that data dynamically from Magento.

Comment: Ah. So you're wanting to get the name of the containing block?

Comment: I think that will work for static blocks, but not for template files although I'm not 100% sure. I researched how to get the name of blocks in Magento and all the results I looked at were how to use static blocks in template files or how to call a static block in a cms page.

Answer (score 0):

The newsletter signup template is in:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Specifically it's the following lines:

```
<li class="control">
    <div class="input-box">
         <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
</li>
```

Additionally the layout for this page can be found in:

```
customer.xml
```

Under the layout handle:

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
```

The lines that define this block:

```
<block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
</block>
```